# Logging Entity changes in Java Web Application

Tags: hibernate, spring, aop

We have a requirement on our project, where we need to maintain a sort of history of changes that are made to certain Entities in the Application. The the Application is a Java Web App based on Struts, Spring and Hibernate. What sort of approaches have been used in this case ?

- Triggers on the respective tables is one idea but they are not easily maintainable ? and perhaps also they should not be part of transactions (its ok if the triggers fail, but the entity update transactions should not fail ).
- Use AoP for this since its a cross-cutting concern, but has to be really granular, as in capturing only the values when the entity changes. (All edits don't have their corresponding different methods... many edits happen in a single java Method).
- Use Hibernate Event Listeners.

Are there any other approaches for doing this sort of activity ?

Answer (score 5):

[JBoss Envers](http://jboss.org/envers) supports audition and versioning - take a look.

Comment: Interesting (+1) Do you use it successfully ??

Comment: @Arhtur - no, alas. But I know people that use it and say it's good :)

Comment: And +1 too. Envers seems to fit well here.

Answer (score 3):

Because you said

> All edits do not have their corresponding different methods... **many edits happen in a single java Method**

Even if your method just receive one argument as parameter and you can retrieve its relationships, AOP still can be a nice idea. I strongly advice you to see this [nice article](http://itmusings.com/java/j2ee/spring-aop-some-recommended-usages)

The Hibernate documentation itself says:

> Hibernate Interceptor allows the application to inspect and/or manipulate properties of a persistent object before it is saved, updated, deleted or loaded. **One possible use for this is to track auditing information.**

But it also says

> **Ensure that you do not store sessionspecific states**, since multiple sessions will use this interceptor potentially concurrently

If you use a Spring managed Transaction, you can get the session atached to the current Thread by using *sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();*

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    if(entity instanceof SomeEntity) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

See [getCurrentSession()](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Hibernate/3.2.4.sp01.cp03/api/hibernate-core/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession()) documentation

If not, you should create a local Hibernate interceptor (attached to the opened Session) instead of a global interceptor(attached to the SessionFactory), and then, set up its session

```
AuditableInterceptor interceptor = new AuditableInterceptor()
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(interceptor);

/**
  * do it before processing anything if you use local interceptor
  */ 
interceptor.setSession(session);
```

About Triggers, it depends on other issues like DB administration (you have DB administration access. If not, Talk to DBA is your best bet).

Comment: Thanks for the info Arthur. For the simple implementation I am trying to extend Hibernate Event Listener.